# Inkscape: "Auto-complete" path from an already existing segment

Tags: inkscape, path

I want to auto-complete an object that is bordering another already-complete objects. These are the two objects I want to manipulate:

[image]

If I move the two objects apart, it looks like this:

[image]

I want to be able to auto-complete the second object into a regular shape so that it looks like this (Really rough sketch) and uses the paths in my other object to complete the border:

[image]

Comment: I guess you have to copy the first shape, cut it at one of the forkings, delete the nodes up to the other forking, then combine it with the open endnodes of the second shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Complete the path-object (right one) so that it overlaps generously with the other object.
- Then double the left one (CTRL+D)
- Select the doubled object (on top!) and the right one
- Then use path difference (CTRL+-) to remove the overlapping part